# css cascade layers in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: css, blazor, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to define a css layer's stack in a custom.css file of a Blazor WASM project using VS 2022, but when it comes to define it, VS start complaining that `"layer" is not a known "@" directive`.
This is an excerpt of the affected code:

effected code portion

[image: 1]

I've tried to search the web for a solution but found early nothing.
Is there someone that came across a similar issue and can help?

Thanks

Comment: But does it work?  They are only warnings, you can probably add a suppress rule.

Comment: no it doesn't...or so it seems. Vendor css has still precedence over my custom one.

Comment: There is no Vendor.css in the question... See if you can make a simple [mre] for this. I think this is 2 problems.

Comment: No **vendor.css** but **vendors' css** (Bootstrap and Materials which are mentioned in the post). 
The use case is layering the Bootstrap and Material css to give precedence to my custom css (app.css) which come last in the layer's stack declaration.
This way I could avoid structure my internal CSS around the third-party code, or escalate conflicts with artificially high specificity or !important flags [link](https://css-tricks.com/css-cascade-layers/#use-cases-when-would-i-want-to-use-cascade-layers)

Comment: Still, neither VS nor the Razor compiler should do anything to the css. The warnings are wrong but harmless, debug this from the running app. I assume that custom.css is last? Always add plenty of details to a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@H.H, you're right. Using the url property of the @import rule and fixing some wrong CSS's relative paths, it's now working as a charm:

```
@layer vendor, blazor;

@import url('bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css') layer(vendor.bootstrap);
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons') layer(vendor.material-icons);
@import url('../_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/material-base.css') layer(vendor.radzen);
@import url('app.css') layer(blazor.app);
```

Now the 3rd party CSS are layerd as expected and my custom.css (unlayerd) takes the precedence.